# How does ibeacon work on background?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon

I want to create a order when someone enters into the iBeacon region on app 
background,but I have a problem when the app on background.

I know if user open "location" and "bluetooth" and enter into region, app will detect the ibeacon.But  after entering into region, user open "bluetooth",the app can't receive the entry notification(sometime work) and can't invoke the function 
`locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region` so the order can't be created.

Does anyone have experience on it?

Answer (score 0):

For more realistic and accurately get bluetooth state value, override its delegate to controller. Core bluetooth framework will help here to get desire accuracy.

Add `<CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>` framework in project.

Use method

`- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral;`

to check bluetooth is powered on?

**[Peripheral Manager State](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CBPeripheralManagerState)** will gives you more details about peripheral state and related delegates.

So when ever device has turn on it's bluetooth, above delegate method will be called.

And here you can manually start to check for region updates.

For Exmaple:

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[_locationManager setDelegate:self];

_beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:<Identifier>];


- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {

    if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected) {
        [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    }
}
```

The method `startRangingBeaconsInRegion` will invoke the method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region;
```

Comment: Thank your.Just now I have tried to do it. When runnig on foreground, the function(bluetooth deleggate) will invoke,but on background  not work. Then I modify background mode  to "App communicates using CoreBluetooth", it still is not work.

Comment: Have a look on this for background bluetooth task - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/plist/info/UIBackgroundModes